# Unable to create directory in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: directory

When i try to run

```
mkdir new
```

I get the error,

```
 bash: cd: new: No such file or directory
```

As far as i remember, i haven't changed any file permissions.So what could be the reason for this.
Ubuntu 10.04

Update:

$ whereis mkdir

mkdir: /bin/mkdir /usr/share/man/man1/mkdir.1.gz /usr/share/man/man2/mkdir.2.gz

$ whereis cd

cd:

o/p for ls -la

```
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 13 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 43 comp comp  4096 2012-04-02 16:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 app
drwxr-xr-x  5 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 config
drwxr-xr-x  2 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 db
drwxr-xr-x  2 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 doc
drwxr-xr-x  3 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 log
drwxr-xr-x  5 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 public
-rw-r--r--  1 comp comp   307 2011-06-15 20:01 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--  1 comp comp 10011 2011-06-15 20:01 README
drwxr-xr-x  3 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 script
drwxr-xr-x  7 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 test
drwxr-xr-x  6 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  3 comp comp  4096 2011-06-15 20:01 vendor
```

Comment: type: `whereis mkdir` & `whereis cd` - send the output!

Comment: Also, do an `ls -la` of the directory where you created the `new` directory and give us the output please!

Comment: @B.Roland i hav updated the qsn.

Comment: Try sudo mkdir if you are not in the home folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this line '`alias mkdir=cd`' 
from ~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: thanx ..it worked